# How to capture still image from a live video programatically

Tags: graphics, directx, video-capture

When i try to take a screenshot of my desktop I found the area of the Windows Media Player window was empty, nothing in it, I google for it for a while and found that most of video players user Overlay surfaces for performance, and overlay surfaces can not be caputured, so some ideas come out said to disable the DDraw accelaration so that you can grap an still image from a live video, but when the player was launched, it's already use the hardware accelaration, even i disable hardware accelaration, it will not take effect until i relaunch the player, my question is: how to capture a image from a live video without diasble the ddraw accelaration? or how to make the settings(disable hardware accelaration) work work without relaunch the video player?

- I won't play the vedio with my program, i just want to take a still
  image while it is played by a 3rd party player such as Windows Media
  Player or Real player etc...
- I want to do this programatically, say
  by C/C++ and DirectX, so I don't want to use any exsisting software
  or tools
- No matter which player in use, my program should capture it, I know some tool can do this like [CapTrue](http://www.captrue.com/download.html) and [tencent qq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tencent_QQ), so i think it is possible to do so.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround can be to use vlc to play your file. It gives a screenshot option in it directly.

Comment: Thank you , but I want to do this programtically by C++ and DirecX

Comment: Then you cannot do so for protected content.YOu have to go down to driver level to get content like that.

Comment: But I know CapTrue and Tencent QQ can do this, I don't think they do this in driver level, since driver vary so much on different video card and system, do they handle all kinds of drivers and systems? it's huge work load, there must be other ways I guess.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is an intentional "feature" in WMP, for protection. If you need to have WMP, then you need a decent screengrabber. Unfortunately, the ones I know like [hypersnap](http://www.hyperionics.com/hsdx/) are not free.

If you only want a screengrab of a frame, VLC is your friend, like @zdd said.

Comment: Sorry, i don't want to play the video with my program, i just want to take a snapshot of it when it is played by a 3rd party player such as WMP or Real player etc.

Comment: I mean i want to do this programatically and no matter which player in use, my program should be able to capture it.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but you could use [BitBlt](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/article.php/c18347/C-Programming-Easy-Screen-Capture-Using-MFCATL.htm) or [WMP API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen).

Comment: No, there is no public APIs can capture the content of Overlay Surface.